# How to format number in the plot_confusion_matrix

Tags: matplotlib, plot, model

How to improve this strange, illegible number format in the matrix so that it shows me only simple numbers?

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

NBC = GaussianNB() 
LRE = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
GBC = GradientBoostingClassifier()
RFC = RandomForestClassifier()
LGBM = LGBMClassifier()
CBC = CatBoostClassifier(verbose=0, n_estimators=100)


classifiers = [NBC,LRE,GBC,RFC,LGBM,CBC]


for cls in classifiers:
    cls.fit(X_train, y_train)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(10,6))
target_names = ['0','1']


for cls, ax in zip(classifiers, axes.flatten()):
    plot_confusion_matrix(cls, 
                          X_test, 
                          y_test, 
                          ax=ax, 
                          cmap='Reds',
                         display_labels=target_names)
    ax.title.set_text(type(cls).__name__)
    
plt.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing a blank value format as the argument to the `plot_confusion_matrix`. The [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html) state

> **values_format : *str, default=None***
>
> Format specification for values in confusion matrix. If None, the format specification is ‘d’ or ‘.2g’ whichever is shorter.

```
plot_confusion_matrix(cls, X_test, y_test, ax=ax, cmap='Reds',
                     display_labels=target_names,
                     values_format='') # <--------- Passed here
```